# Is var used when we do Spark programming in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

It looks like ***val*** is always used, I haven't seen ***var*** used in Spark programs. So just curious what the reason would be behind this. What I understand is that RDD is immutable and we will not want to do a change or update to an existing RDD. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var` in your program but it's not recommended way in functional style.

Scala supports both [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) paradigm but it encourages users to use functional approach whenever possible. One of the main advantages of functional style is that you tell computer *what* to do not *how* to do things. But there are some scenarios where imperative style would be more suitable.

In functional approach, use of immutable objects are promoted, where you do not need to worry about the state of the variable, specially in concurrent programming to make code safer and cleaner. But there are scenarios where using mutable objects (`var`) is more appropriate like when creation of object is very costly than simply changing few properties of the object.

So the usage of `val` or `var` depends on the task in hand. It's not that one way is *always* better than the other, it's purely based on the problem.

`val` and `var` are not restricted to a particular tool / framework, it's a general concept in Scala. So when you say:

> It looks like `val` is always used, I haven't seen `var` used in Spark
>   programs.

It's because Spark generally uses and encourages programmers to use functional approach.

Answer (score 1):

One of the common ways I use `var` in Spark programming is when I am creating objects that need to be initialized separately on the executors. In that case, I will define a `var` in the object that is `null` or `None` until some even intializes it. The `var` is hidden, and just maintains internal state.

For example, I'll create an object like this:

```
object DoesntSerialize {
  var avroParser: Option[Schema.Parser] = None

  def useParser(schemas: Array[String], record: GenericData.Record) : Array[Byte] = {
    if (avroParser.isEmpty) {
      initParser(schemas)
    }

    encodeRecord(record)
  }

  def encodeRecord(record: GenericData.Record) : Array[Byte] = {
    ...
  }

  def initParser(schemas: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then in my code, I can just use the object, and the first time the object is used on each executor `initParser` is called.

Comment: Note that `lazy val` can be used for this if you want to avoid `var`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a case that I found `var` used in an example with an RDD from the book [Spark In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spark-in-action) section 4.1.2

`var transByCust = ...// create pair RDD, key = customer ID, value = purchase info`

The explanation for using `var` is "... variable so that you can keep RDDs containing new and changed transactions (which you'll calculate later) in a single variable and just update it."

For example, the author will later apply discounts to some customers based on their purchases.

I do not know if this is considered good or bad practice and if that was meant only for pedagogical purpose.